# How to update a table in a Word document that has multiple tables?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have multiple tables in a Word file.
First I want to search a table containing name with column1 as `name` and column2 as `content`.
After searching, update the table of column2 and row2 with the data "input" when the `checkbox` is pressed. Checkbox named as `sens1`.

The code gives me the error

> Table with column names 'name' and 'content' not found`

A table with the same name exists.

[image: table and checkbox details]

```vb
Public Sub UpdateTable()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim foundTable As Boolean
    foundTable = False
    
    'Loop through all tables in the document
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        'Check if the first column name is "name" and the second column name is "content"
        If tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "name" And tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "content" Then
            foundTable = True
            
            'Update the cell value if checkbox is checked
            If ActiveDocument.FormFields("sens1").CheckBox.Value = True Then
                tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = "input"
            Else
                tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = ""
            End If
            
            Exit For
        End If
    Next tbl
    
    'Check if the table was found
    If Not foundTable Then
        MsgBox "Table with column names 'name' and 'content' not found"
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I want to use this in other Word documents having a different index.
With name it would be useful for other documents.

Comment: Did you create the document that has the tables? You can add bookmarks to them to find them later.

Comment: Yeah. For the time being, I have created the document with more than 1 table and trying to execute the above code.

Comment: If their indexes are always the same, then you can use that to identify them.

Comment: Yeah, but with the same name I want to use in different word documents having the different index. So, if I got the way with then name it would be more useful for other documents.

Comment: The range.text for a table cell is always terminated by a cell marker which you need to remove before you compare with "name" etc.

Comment: @jonsson you mean to say that I need to remove the spaces of the first colum.

Comment: I mean that you need something more like If left(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, len(t l.Cell(1,1).Range.Text)-2)= "name" and something similar for the other comparison.